# Sending sensor data to apache Kafka using UDP

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, sensors, iot

In my system, there are many sensors generating data. I want they send generated data to Kafka, directly without interfering network programming.

As I know, Kafka(Confluent version) support HTTP for such situations, but my sensors don't send data using Http protocol and they have their own protocol.

Now my questions are:

1. Kafka received(understand) in which network layout data abstraction?
   I mean it can receive data in binary(Physical network layout data)
   or higher data abstraction layout like Datalink layout, network layout, ...
2. Is that any way to send data to Kafka directly?
3. If not, is it possible to customize Kafka source code to fit the
   situation?

**Generally**, is it possible to send data from sensors to Kafka using UDP protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [`KafkaProducer`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) that consumes your format, or alternatively convert your format into a suitable text format and pipe that into Kafka's generic `kafka-console-producer.sh`.

Comment: `KafkaProducer` is a Java/Scala class that send data to Kafka brokers. How I use it while the sensor cannot be programmed!

Comment: Kafka has its own protocol - if you want to send data to it, your sender need to obey this protocol.

Comment: @soheil If the sensor cannot be programmed and yield only a proprietary data format, you'll perhaps need intermediate nodes where you do the necessary conversion. This is not specific to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bridge to Kafka in a node to transform those messages to something Kafka can understand (something like an envelope).

You can find an implementation of such software in Github

https://github.com/agaoglu/udp-kafka-bridge

This one is used to send syslog messages to a Kafka topic.